# How get block with data from remote html?

Tags: php, dom, file-get-contents

**Good day.**

***For get remote html i use code:***

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://who.is/whois/abate.com');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Prevents Warnings, remove if desired
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($file);
```

***And i get html:***

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
    <th>Expires On</th>
    <td><span data-bind-domain="expiration_date" style="visibility: visible;">November 28, 2015</span></td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
    <th>Registered On</th>
    <td><span data-bind-domain="expiration_date" style="visibility: visible;">June 03, 1995</span></td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
    <th>Updated On</th>
    <td><span data-bind-domain="expiration_date" style="visibility: visible;">June 01, 2013</span></td>
    </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

***I would like get:***

1) date Expires On

2) date Registered On

3) date Updated On

***Anyone have ideas how make it ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the following block of code runs, `$values` should contain the expiration, registration, and update dates of the domain name:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = $xpath->evaluate('//table/tbody/tr[th="Expires On" or th="Registered On" or th="Updated On"]/td/span');

$values = array();
foreach($result as $node) {
    $values[] = $node->textContent;
}
```

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "November 28, 2015"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "June 03, 1995"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "June 01, 2013"
}
```